# Cannot read property in ionic cordova build android --prod --release

Tags: android, cordova, typescript, ionic-framework, production

Im trying to build my apk for deploying the application in the playstore. Here is the error. Im really out of time and I have to fix this error as soon as possible. Any reference about this is much appreciated.

```
ionic cordova build android --prod --release
Running app-scripts build: --prod --platform android --target cordova
[09:25:34]  build prod started ...
[09:25:35]  clean started ...
[09:25:35]  clean finished in 12 ms
[09:25:35]  copy started ...
[09:25:36]  deeplinks started ...
[09:25:37]  deeplinks finished in 601 ms
[09:25:37]  ngc started ...
Warning: Can't resolve all parameters for AngularFirestore in E:/sdg-biz-mobile/node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/index.d.ts: ([object Object], ?). This will become an error in Angular v6.x
Warning: Can't resolve all parameters for AngularFirestore in E:/sdg-biz-mobile/node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/index.d.ts: ([object Object], ?). This will become an error in Angular v6.x
TypeError: Cannot read property 'flags' of undefined
    at checkUnreachable (E:\sdg-biz-mobile\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:24905:31)
    at bindChildrenWorker (E:\sdg-biz-mobile\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:23111:17)
    at bindChildren (E:\sdg-biz-mobile\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:23055:17)
    at bind (E:\sdg-biz-mobile\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:24319:21)
    at bindSourceFile (E:\sdg-biz-mobile\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:22689:17)
    at Object.bindSourceFile (E:\sdg-biz-mobile\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:22640:9)
    at initializeTypeChecker (E:\sdg-biz-mobile\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:47988:20)
    at Object.createTypeChecker (E:\sdg-biz-mobile\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:27142:9)
    at getDiagnosticsProducingTypeChecker (E:\sdg-biz-mobile\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:69678:93)
    at emitWorker (E:\sdg-biz-mobile\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:69722:32)
[09:25:50]  copy finished in 14.73 s
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced this type of errors.Below solution is helped me.

**Step1:**

```
rm -rf node_modules
```

**Step2:**

```
npm cache clean --force
```

**Step3:**

```
Delete package_lock.json
```

**Step4:**

```
npm install
```

I hope it will help you.